# apt-get update failing on Debian based Docker image hosted on DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

My docker image is based on `mongo:3.6.5` and I am running the command `apt-get update` on it. While it is executing successfully on my local machine, I am getting the following error messages after trying to host it on a Ubuntu 16.04 DigitalOcean droplet.

```
root@93c75f4d76a9:/# apt-get update
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to security.debian.org:http:
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease

Err http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
Err http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease

Err http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to repo.mongodb.org:http:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/jessie/mongodb-org/3.6/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to security.debian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/dists/jessie/mongodb-org/3.6/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to repo.mongodb.org:http:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I found similar issues and tried with changing the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` file by adding

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

I tried to find and edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` file which does not exist on this droplet.

Also tried to disable `ufw` service as mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/apt-get-update-error-w-failed-to-fetch-mirrors-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-ignored-or-old-ones-used-instead) which is not existent on this droplet as well.

Further I used docker image from `node:8.11.3` which is also Debian based and tried to execute the same `apt-get update` command but with same errors.

Even after removing all the docker images with `docker system prune -a` and re-downloading it to avoid cache builds, couldn't find any rescue.

Any workaround on this particular scenario would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you running apt-get update on a prebuilt docker image?  One of the reasons to containerize is to have an immutable application deployment.

Comment: One of the reasons of containerization is also that we don't have to iterate similar tasks repeatedly. The case here is that the `Dockerfile` is importing using `FROM mongo:3.6.5` and the next command is `RUN apt-get update` followed by other `RUN` commands